# How do I run the 'openni_tracker'

Tags: openni, openi-tracker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

i have done the following tutorial ' http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_camera '
now i want to for tracking but i could not do anything mentioned on this page
' http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_tracker '

Can anyone help me on this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10325/how-do-i--run-the-%27openni_tracker%27/) by [Jay](https://answers.ros.org/users/714/jay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-06-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-06-20**:
Please edit your post instead of commenting, the formatting is much better in the question.

**Comment by [Jay](https://answers.ros.org/users/714/jay/) on 2011-06-20**:
rosrun openni_tracker openni_tracker

After running above command I got the following message; but I could not get the view window.
:

New User 1
New User 2
Lost user 1
New User 1
Lost user 2
Lost user 1
New User 1
Lost user 1
New User 1
New User 2
Lost user 2
Lost user 1
New User 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Openni_tracker doesn't display anything.  You can view the frames using a transform visualization in rviz.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Many seem to be having a lot of issues utilizing openni_tracker.  Hopefully this helps:

I am using ROS Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04 with a Microsoft Kinect.  From top to bottom, this is what worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-<ros_distro>-openni-camera
sudo apt-get install ros-<ros_distro>-openni-launch
sudo apt-get install ros-<ros_distro>-openni-tracker
```

Go to [this Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/sh/jsygeyx8dwa49w6/AAA-XmOWcz9svJBZQ_VKMS3ha) from isura (Thanks) and download `NITE-Bin-Linux-x64-v1.5.2.23.tar.zip`.
Extract the zip and tar into a temporary folder (i.e., ~/tmp).

```
cd ~/tmp/NITE-Bin-Dev-Linux-x64-v1.5.2.23/
sudo ./install.sh
```

Ensure your Microsoft Kinect is properly connected, then run:

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni_launch camera:=openni
```

In a separate terminal window run:

```
rosrun openni_tracker openni_tracker
```

In another terminal window run:

```
rosrun rviz rviz
```

In Rviz, change Global Options > Fixed Frame to openni_depth_optical_frame.

"Add" the visualization (bottom left) PointCloud2.

Change PointCloud2 >Topic to /openni/depth_registered/points (but whatever you pick works).

"Add" the visualization (bottom left) TF.

Stand in front of the Microsoft Kinect and make the "Psi Pose".  Axes should appear on all your joints.

I hope this helps you.  There are a lot of different versions of NITE out there and this is the one that happened to work for me.

---

Originally posted by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) with karma: 323 on 2015-02-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1